# Is there a feat that improves one's level for Rage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, barbarian, rage

Is there a feat that can improve a character's level for the purpose of Rage? For example, something similar to [Boon Companion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/boon-companion/) but for the rage class feature?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game and edition you're asking about?

Comment: Boon companion is a pathfinder feat, but we need to be sure that this is the game you are asking about. Adding the [pathfinder] tag to your question helps us identify the game.

Comment: I'm wondering if you mean Class Level instead of character level, please see this discussion: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14619/class-level-vs-character-level-vs-my-level

Answer (score 1):

## In short, no.

While there are no feats that specifically increase the bonuses of raging as if you were higher level in official materials, there are a couple that augment barbarian rage in different ways:

**Raging Vitality** (*Advanced Player's Guide*)

> While raging, you are full of vigor and health.
>
> *Prerequisites*: Con 15, rage class feature.
>
> *Benefit*: Whenever you are raging, the morale bonus to your Constitution increases by +2. Your rage does not end if you become unconscious. While unconscious you must still expend rounds of rage per day each round.

**Raging Brutality** (*Ultimate Combat*)

> You expend some of your rage to strike your opponents with a more powerful weapon blow.
>
> *Prerequisites*: Str 13, rage class feature, Power Attack, base attack bonus +12.
>
> *Benefit*: While raging and using Power Attack, you can spend 3 additional rounds of your rage as a swift action to add your Constitution bonus on damage rolls for melee attacks or thrown weapon attacks you make on your turn. If you are using the weapon two-handed, instead add 1-1/2 times your Constitution bonus. This bonus damage is not multiplied on a critical hit.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Be sure to check out the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any questions.